# Solving Limits: Why must I multiply by Conjugate? $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ √(n+1) - √n

Tags: limits, analysis

Sorry if the question strikes as you as dumb, but the last time I had math in school was 15 years ago and now I'm taking a course, requiring me to do some math.

So in the course material, the teacher solved this one  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n+1}$- $\sqrt{n}$ by multiply with a conjugate and she got the result of 0.

I tried solving it, without looking at here solution first and what I did was using the theorems to solve it as follow:
$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$$\sqrt{n+1}$ - $\sqrt{n}$ =

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n+1}$ -$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n}$ =

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n}$ + $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{1}$ - $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n}$ =

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n}$ + 1 - $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ $\sqrt{n}$ =

1 #

Why is that? and why must I multiply by conjugate? and when should one multiply by conjugate, any specific rules or tips?

I'd be grateful, if you could make your answer as detailed and simple as possible, since as I mentioned before, it's been a while since I had anything to do with math.

Comment: What do you think "$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n$" is?

Comment: And BTW : $\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt n+\sqrt1$ is the kind of thing that makes me have nightmares when I read my students' work...

Comment: Almost no operator is distributive over a square root, the limit is not an exception. If you find yourself "splitting" a root you are almost surely on the wrong path.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS that's because all your students take $n=0$ $\ddot\smile$ hahaha

Comment: *why must I multiply by conjugate* --- You don't. There are other ways to evaluate the limit, and you can also multiply/divide by non-conjugates such as $\sqrt{n^2 - 1} + \sqrt{n^2 - n}.$

Comment: @manooooh : doesn't make me feel any better :-[

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I thought that the limit of the square root of any number n minus the limit of the square root of the same number n, would be zero, or?

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS sorry to add to your nightmares, it just has been long since I did any real math. :D

Comment: @noobnomore : that's OK, but please don't do it again :-)

Comment: @N74 so this is what I did wrong, I just looked it up and square root is only distributive with multiplication and division, thanks a lot!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro what did you do there? I didn't get that.

Comment: The standard algebraic method is to multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}.$ However, it's easy to see (because the extra common factor I'm including winds up canceling out) that you can also multiply and divide by $2\sqrt{n+1} + 2\sqrt{n},$ or multiply and divide by $n\sqrt{n+1} + n\sqrt{n},$ or multiply and divide by $\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n^2 - 1} + \sqrt{n^2 - n}.$ The last is what I gave earlier. It's analogous to getting a common denominator when adding fractions. You don't have to have a *least* common denominator; any common denominator works.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro that seems like Magic for someone like me :). Thank you for taking the time to explain this. Could you maybe point me to some learning material to brush up on the knowledge gaps I've now?

Comment: I'd need to know a lot more about your background to know what background to recommend, plus it depends on your future plans. Perhaps what could be of use to you are one or more of the books I mentioned in my answer to [Mathematics books to master limits.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2760914/mathematics-books-to-master-limits/2767608#2767608)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro sorry for the late reply, but has been a busy week.
So it's like this, I've not had any contact with math for the last 15 years and I'm currently doing an Analysis course for computer science. I can read and write in English, German and Arabic so any book of these languages can be helpful to me. I'd want something that explains the basics in details for me and also with exercises and answers and not very long, because I don't have much time for this course I'm doing. is that enough as a background? you can think of me as math-illiterate  :'(

Comment: I think the simplest and quickest solution for you would be to visit a college/university library with pen/pencil and paper, go to where calculus books are located (around QA 300 in library of congress classification), and flip through the limit sections of several (dozens if you have time) standard calculus texts and look over the worked examples, jotting down those you need help with, perhaps all radical types on one page of notes, all trig. types on another page of notes, etc. Most of the things you need are standard algebraic manipulation techniques **(continued)**

Comment: you probably once knew from high school algebra/precalculus, so you'll be looking for standard techniques that seem to show up over and over in the examples, such as radical rationalization methods, basic trig. identities and ways of multiplying by $1$ written in clever ways, how to work with absolute values and piecewise defined functions, etc. The first part of [this worksheet](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-1874348-6544585-537993/cal_1W1.pdf) gives some standard methods in the hints. There are also a lot of "solved problems" and "review" series **(continued)**

Comment: of books for lower level courses such as calculus (and physics, genetics, engineering mechanics, etc.) that you'll find at most every college/university bookstore, such as the [Schaum's Outline for Calculus](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071795537), [this book that I don't know anything about](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071638156), [this other book I don't know anything about](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0812098196), [and yet another book I don't know anything about](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1592575129), . . . As a glanced at these, Chapter 10 of the last book looks promising. **(continued)**

Comment: *(Beginning with last sentence, because time ran out before I could correct it.)* As I glanced at these, Chapter 10 of the last book looks promising. At least, this is the kind of thing you want to see if you're just quickly looking through the table of contents of books in a library, bookstore, online, etc.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Wow! amazing advice! Thank you so much for taking the time to give me such a detailed and good advice! I'll definitely do as you say and see what I can find. I find math pretty interesting, but I'd a couple of math teachers that weren't and made kind of dislike math.However, as I'm learning on my own, I can say it's frustrating, but very interesting too. Again, Thank you so much and have a great sunday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a step by step look at what you did.

**1.** $\lim_n (\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}) = \lim_n \sqrt{n+1}-\lim_n \sqrt n$

This is wrong, since the right hand side is in the indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$. It can be any real number and it can be $\pm\infty$. Thus, there is no sensible way to define it, just like there is no sensible way to define $\frac 00$.

To demonstrate more vividly why this is wrong, let $a$ be any real number. Then $$ a = \lim_n  a = \lim_n  (n+a-n) = \lim_n (n+a) - \lim_n  n = \infty - \infty.$$ If $b$ is another real number, by the same reasoning as above, we get $b = \infty - \infty$. Thus, $a = \infty - \infty = b$, so any two real numbers are equal.

Whoops, we just broke math.

**2.** $\lim_n \sqrt{n+1} = \lim_n \sqrt n + \lim_n  \sqrt 1.$

Ah, this one is not as wrong since contrary to the case $\infty - \infty$, one can actually make sense of $\infty + a = \infty$, for any real number $a$. However $\infty$ **is still not a number** and you can't do arithmetic with it as usual. For example, $\infty + a = \infty = \infty + b$, for any real $a$ and $b$. Notice that you can't cancel $\infty$ on both sides like you would with some real number $x$ to conclude $a = b$. That would break math once again.

So, if one is careful and *knows what they are doing*, $\infty + 1 = \infty$ is a fair game. **However**, in the same line you have $-\lim_n \sqrt n = -\infty$ and you remember what we said about subtracting infinity from infinity: it breaks math.

Thus, your line is still wrong.

Unfortunately, it's likely that it's even more wrong. I'm afraid that you wrote that thinking that $\sqrt{n+1} = \sqrt n + \sqrt 1$. No. Please, no. Nicolas FRANCOIS and I are both having nightmares tonight. Just plug in $n = 8$ and calculate both sides. Doesn't work.

**3.** $\lim_n \sqrt n + 1 - \lim_n \sqrt n = 1$.

Looks correct, but as I said before, subtracting infinity from infinity breaks math. It would have been correct if it said $\lim_n (\sqrt n -\sqrt n) + 1 = 1$. But it doesn't say that.

---

**TL;DR** Please use the rule $\lim_n (a_n+b_n) = \lim_n  a_n + \lim_n  b_n$ only if it doesn't produce $\infty - \infty$. If $\lim_n  a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_n  b_n$ is $\infty$ or finite, then $\lim_n (a_n+b_n) = \infty$. If $\lim_n  a_n = \infty$ and $\lim_n  b_n = -\infty$, then $\lim_n (a_n+b_n)$ can be anything under the heavens.

---

So, hopefully I've stressed enough that $\infty - \infty$ is a no no. So, how to deal with it?

Observe that $a-b = \frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{(a+b)} = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$ and so $$\lim_n(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n) = \lim_n\frac{(n+1)-n}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} = \lim_n\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n} = \left[ \frac 1{\infty + \infty} = \frac 1\infty\right] = 0.$$

This is actually a great strategy whenever you have $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: that is an amazing answer, I like the part about breaking math :D. Many many thanks for the detailed and beautiful answer. Could I burden you to point me to some sites/books/materials in general to fill in such gaps that I've? I'll be doing analysis and I keep noticing those gaps, but I've no clue where to start and I don't have much time as the course time isn't long enough.

Comment: @noobnomore, I'm glad to help, you are welcome. Unfortunately, I don't teach in English, so I don't really know good sources for introductory analysis. The books I know in English are advanced and likely not suited for your needs. I'd recommend that you search math.SE, there is almost certainly many reference requests for what you need.

Comment: that's in Swedish, so I'll just have to rely on google translate :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the Limit is of the form $$\infty-\infty$$ which is indeterminate, so you mut write
$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt n$$

in an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$ therefore we need some trick and manipilation to solve it. One standard method is use that

$$(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$$

and therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt n) \frac{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{n+1})^2 -(\sqrt n)^2}{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n+1-n}{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1} +\sqrt n}$$

which is in the form $\frac 1{\infty}$ and can be easily evaluated.

As an alternative we can also use others more advanced methods as for example by binomial theorem we have

$$\sqrt{n+1}=\sqrt n \sqrt{1+1/n}=\sqrt n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^\frac12\sim\sqrt n\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)=\sqrt n +\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$

and therefore

$$\sqrt{n+1} -\sqrt n\sim \sqrt n +\frac1{2\sqrt n}-\sqrt n=\frac1{2\sqrt n}$$